# Maximum likelihood estimation of system of correlated SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, correlation, parameter-estimation

I have the following system of SDEs (which you can think of as 3 different stocks)
$$dX_t^1 = \mu_t X_t^1 dt + \sigma_t X_t^1 dW_t^1$$
$$dX_t^2 = \mu_2 dt + \sigma_2 dW_t^2$$
$$dX_t^3 = \mu_3 dt + \sigma_3 dW_t^3$$
where $dW_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and correlated such that
$dW_t^1 dW_t^2 = \rho_2 dt$ and $dW_t^1 dW_t^3 = \rho_3 dt$. I have discrete time series data on $X_t^1$,
$X_t^2$ and $X_t^3$, and they are all sampled at the same time. How do I find maximum likelihood estimators in this model?

My initial thought was to rewrite the setup to a system in terms of $X_t^i$ instead of $dX_t^i$, apply Cholesky decomposition
and then use MLE for multivariate normal variables. But I am unsure how to do this specifically, and if that is the best approach to estimate parameters in a system of correlated SDEs?

Comment: I think there's a typo in your question because the first line looks different from the second and the third.

Comment: It's not a typo :)

Comment: So the processes for the second and third do not follow the same process as the first ?

Comment: No, the first SDE is a standard GMB with time-dependent drift and volatility. The second and third are simplified versions. They are driven by a standard Brownian motion, where correlation is introduced. 

I'm a bit worried of the MLE approach, as it requires i.i.d. random variables. The time-dependence in the drift and volatility in the first SDE ruins that...

Comment: Okay. Thanks. My only suggestion is to write out the discrete versions of the three processes. With those written down, somebody may be able to figure out the joint likelihood. Note that the MLE doesn't require i.i.d random variables IF one can write out the joint likelihood.

Comment: @Spandaver In the first equation, $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are two functions? I think you meant $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$.